# Unable to collect spark dataset as list or map with No applicable constructor error

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Store {

    private Double probability;

    private String store;

}
```

and json file

```
{"probability":"0.26","store":"abc/s3"}
{"probability":"0.57","store":"abc/s1"}
```

I try to read it as a dataset and convert it to map. Reading as dataset is successful and able to operate on it using spark sql commands and also able to view the dataset using show(), etc

```
Dataset<Store> ds = ss.read().json(path).as(Encoders.bean(Store.class));
Map<String, Double> storeMap = ds.collectAsList().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Store::getStore, Store::getProbability));
```

But converting to map fails with error. This error is on the command ds.collectAsList() itself

```
No applicable constructor/method found for actual parameters 

"org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String"; 
candidates are: 
"public static java.lang.Double java.lang.Double.valueOf(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.NumberFormatException",
"public static java.lang.Double java.lang.Double.valueOf(double)"
```

What am i doing wrong  ?

Comment: can you check this column - probability values in your json file, are you getting all doubles ? also can you show your ds schema ?, reading as dataset is successful because it will read that column value as string. problem is converting string to double.. i feel you column has some string values which cannot be parsed to double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is not in your code but in your JSON data . It should be

```
{"probability":0.26,"store":"abc/s3"}
{"probability":0.57,"store":"abc/s1"}
```

Or change `private Double probability;`  to     `private String probability;`